# Komodo Edit, No PHP autocomplete and calltips with XAMPP

Tags: php, autocomplete, xampp, komodo, komodoedit

I got a real problem with Komodo Edit v8.5.3: *I use XAMPP  XAMPP v1.8.3 [PHP: 5.5.6] to provide a local hosted server for Komodo.*

```
[Edit -> Preferences -> Languages -> PHP] ; here I configured the PHP stuff like this:

**Default PHP Interpreter** C:\xampp\php\php.exe

**Path to alternate PHP configuration file** C:\xampp\php\php.ini

**PHP Directories** nothing
```

After restarting I tested this feature: But no autocomplet and calltips, syntax checking did sometimes work ...
If I wrote some code, it began to scan the php directory of XAMPP for completing, but this search got freezed everytime somewhere (in the PEAR directory).

I don't really understand what's wrong with Komodo and XAMPP. (I did also reinstall Komodo.)

Komodo is great, but withoutd this the most importent feature is impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Komodo php autocomplete didn't work for me, too.

My situation might be different, but I'm sharing for the next Googler to visit.

I installed Komodo **before** php5. Whoops. Installing php wasn't good enough, I had to also delete the config files in `~/.komodo-edit` (or whatever folder it created).

That still wasn't enough, I also had to delete the `___.komodoproject` file I was working on as well.

Then I was awed by Komodo's awesomeness.

Answer (score 1):

Komodo Edit 8.5.3 has a memory leak problem.  To confirm this check your process list and you will see Komodo Edit main thread and Python child thread.  Watch to see the memory footprint of the Python thread as the scan progresses.

If the memory is large (for me is was over 1GB), try upgrading to a later release.

At time of writing this, you can find version 8.5.4 here:

http://downloads.activestate.com/Komodo/nightly/komodoide/latest/